# Objc EXC_BAD_ACCESS when setting a NSString equal to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I'm having some really REALLY weird issues with NSString. When I read from an input stream and convert the data to a string I'm not able to set anything equal to that string. Here's the code:

```
NSString *name = r.URL.lastPathComponent;
NSString *data;
NSInputStream *stream = r.HTTPBodyStream;
uint8_t byteBuffer[1];
[stream open];

if (stream)
{
    // Get the request body from the stream. Used for setting the file name
    if (stream.hasBytesAvailable)
    {
        NSInteger bytesRead = [stream read:byteBuffer maxLength:4096];
        NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:byteBuffer length:bytesRead encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        data = temp; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS thrown here
    }
}
```

I need to copy the string over to another string but I can't. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your byte buffer is one byte big but you're reading 4096 bytes into it. This is likely to trigger a cascading sequence of events that culminates into the crash.

Comment: You're absolutely right, the behavior was so weird. I was like "what's going on." but yea, I was overwriting random sections in memory. Changing the buffer size fixed everything.

Comment: @Minimi, you may want to get into the habit of using sizeof(byteBuffer) instead of a fixed number.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't mark it because it hadn't been 8 min then I forgot, got to it today though!

Comment: Also, I'm using sizeof(byteBuffer) to avoid hardcoding the wrong numbers.